# Can you run DB2 commands from a jdbc connection

Tags: jdbc, db2

I cannot install or use a DB2 tool to issue commands to DB2 such as killing long running applications. I can however have a jdbc connection to DB2 to run queries. Is there a way to issue DB2 commands from just a jdbc connection? I’m currently using SQL Workbench for queries but it doesn’t seem to have any place for commands. I also cannot pay for a tool as this goes through the company and they wouldn’t approve.

Comment: What operating-system runs the Db2-server?  z/os, i-series,  linux/unix/windows.

Comment: IBM Data Studio is free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out the [admin_cmd procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0012547.html)

With this procedure you can run a couple of commands but the options may be limited - so make sure to read the documentation referenced above.